# .Net Core - Invoke all implementations of a generic interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, dependency-injection

I'm trying to reach this functionality:
`Interface`:

```
public interface IAppRepository<T> where T: IAppEvent
{
    Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> GetAllEventsByDateTimeAsync(DateTime eventsBeforeDate);
    Task DeleteEventAsync(string internalRequestId);
}

public class SampleEvent: IAppEvent
{
    public string InternalRequestId { get; set; }
}
    
public class SpecialEvent: IAppEvent
{
    public string InternalRequestId { get; set; }
}
```

`Startup`:

```
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IAppRepository<SpecialEvent>, SpecialRepository>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IAppRepository<SampleEvent>, SampleRepo>();
```

`Resolve`:

```
public class RepositoryResolver : IRepositoryResolver
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public RepositoryResolver(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IAppRepository<T> Get<T>() where T : class, IAppEvent
    {
        return (IAppRepository<T>)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IAppRepository<T>));
    }
}
```

`Events`:

```
public class SampleEvent: IAppEvent
{
    public string InternalRequestId { get; set; }
}
        
public class SpecialEvent: IAppEvent
{
    public string InternalRequestId { get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to call all existing implementations of `IAppRepository` and call their `Delete` method

something like:

```
foreach(IAppRepository repo in GetAllRepos())
{
    var oldEvents = repo.GetAllEventsByDateTimeAsync(DateTime.Now);
    foreach(IAppEvent event in oldEvents)
    {
        repo.DeleteEventAsync(event.InternalRequestId);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do that? Or I need to invoke every repository by its event type?

Answer (score 0):

The idea was to use reflection to search for all your implemented type, step two might be seeing as not so necessary, but I usually choose a safer way.

```
// Assembly that repos implemented 
var destinationAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IAppRepository<>));

var implementedTypes = destinationAssembly!.GetTypes().Where(x =>
    !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface && x.BaseType != null && x.GetInterfaces()
        .Any(i => i.IsGenericType && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IAppRepository<>)));

var sp = HttpContext.RequestServices; // Replace with your service provider instance;
// Call as needed, make sure you register all the repos
foreach (var instanceType in implementedTypes)
{
    var instance = sp.GetService(instanceType.GetInterfaces()
        .First(x => x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IAppRepository<>)));
    var methodToInvoke = instance!.GetType().GetMethod("Your Method Name"); // In this case [DeleteEventAsync]
    methodToInvoke!.Invoke(instance, new []{"Your Request Id"});
}
```

On step two, Your repo can be in many form of implementing `IAppRepository<>` interface like

```
public class SpecialRepository : IAppRepository<SpecialEvent>
public class SpecialRepository<T> : IAppRepository<SpecialEvent> where T: class
public abstract class BaseRepository : IAppRepository<SpecialEvent>
// Many more
```

So only filter actual implemented types is safer, tweak it as you wish to fit specific use cases